# background filtering MRI image

Tags: matlab, background, filtering

I wanted to filter out my image using morphology so that I could just have the main image, however, the images I produce are of a non compatible type. How should I make the two the same image type to execute the code, or what should I do instead?

```
info = dicominfo('MR000025.dcm');
>> Z = dicomread(info);
>> I=imadjust(Z,stretchlim(Z),[0 1]);
>>  figure, imshow(I)
>> background = imopen(I,strel('disk',10));
figure,imshow(background)
>> 

>> background = imopen(I,strel('disk',15));
>> figure,imshow(background)
>> figure, surf(double(background(1:8:end,1:8:end))),zlim([0 255]);
set(gca,'ydir','reverse');

>> I2 = I - background;
figure, imshow(I2)
>> I3 = imadjust(I2);
figure, imshow(I3);
>> level = graythresh(I3);
bw = im2bw(I3,level);
bw = bwareaopen(bw, 50);
figure, imshow(bw)
>> I4 = I - bw;
figure, imshow(I4)

Error using  - 
Integers can only be combined with integers of
the same class, or scalar doubles.

>> i=im2uint8(I);
>> i4=i-bw;
Error using  - 
Integers can only be combined with integers of
the same class, or scalar doubles.

>> i2=gray2ind(bw);
>> i3=i-i2;
>> figure, imshow(i3)
>>
```

Comment: Can we see a `class(i), class(bw), class(I)` to see why matlab cowardly refuses to do the computation?

Comment: >class(i)

    >ans =

    >uint8

    >class(bw)
    >class(I)

    >ans =

    >uint8


    >ans =

    >int16

Answer (score 1):

It's because bw is a logical type. If you add:

```
bw = bwareaopen(bw, 50);
bw = uint8(255*bw);
```

Your errors will go away. But the code may not work as expected...

Instead, ignore above.

Try this:

```
I4 = I;
I4(bw)=0;
```

Instead of

```
I4 = I - bw;
```

EDIT:

Noticed you are using graythresh which means it was RGB to start so the above will need tweaking:

```
I4 = I;
I4(repmat(bw,[1 1 3]))=0;
```